# Python cursor.execute fetchall questions

Tags: python

I was trying to get results from SQL server using below queries, the results are combined in one columns but I want the results break out in three columns for AID, BID, Dates. Is there any ways to achieve this?

```
sends = cursor.execute('''
                   SELECT AID, BID, Dates FROM db 
                   WHERE Dates BETWEEN ? AND ?
                   ''',StartDate, EndDate)
sends_dt = pd.DataFrame(sends.fetchall())
sends_dt.head()


Result:
        0
0  [43278, 61508, 2020-07-31 ]
1  [43274, 61515, 2020-07-31 ]
2  [43274, 61575, 2020-07-31 ]
3  [43273, 61562, 2020-07-31 ]
4  [43274, 61819, 2020-07-31 ]

Result wanted:
     0        1        2                     
0  43278, 66888, 2020-07-31 
1  43274, 61505, 2020-07-31 
2  43274, 61565, 2020-07-31 
3  43273, 61532, 2020-07-31 
4  43274, 61809, 2020-07-31
```

Comment: Is `sends_dt` a dataframe (pandas)?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 0):

When creating a DataFrame, you can specify columns.

Try this:

```
results = sends.fetchall()
if results:
    sends_dt = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['AID', 'BID', 'Dates'])
```

It'll even look prettier as each column will have  a description.

Comment: Thank you I tried, but it gives me error that "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (73659564, 1), indices imply (73659564, 3)"

Comment: Please share the result of  `print(sends.fetchall())` and `print(type(sends.fetchall()))`

Comment: print(sends.fetchall())
[]

print(type(sends.fetchall()))
<class 'list'>

Comment: @databeginner Make sure you have something in the database. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can set column headers this way:

```
sends_dt.columns =['AID', 'BID', 'Dates']
```

replace `sends_dt.head()` with the above line in your code

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it gives me error 'ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 3 elements'